# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python

I'm getting this error and don't understand why! Any ideas anyone?

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is my code.

```
import math
from lib import *
from test import *

hostCal = (int((200 * 0.7) / 10))
```

Basically my requirement is I just want to convert the float value into integer. When I execute just .py file it works fine but when I imported .py file into Robot I getting the above error.

Comment: What is the complete backtrace you're getting (not just the exception itself)?

Comment: oops While copy pasted I missed ")"

Answer (score 4):

Either your `lib` module or your `test` module contains a binding of the name `int` to a string value.

(Moral of the story: avoid `from <module> import *`!)

Comment: lib and test module doesn't contain any name with "int". Is there any other alternative to convert the float value to int?

Comment: @Siya Then there's probably an error in one of those modules. Can't tell without seeing a full traceback. (An alternative? Yes: `__builtins__.int` instead of `int`, but I suspect it'll crash before it gets there.)